# symfony image inside a button?

Tags: php, html, symfony1, symfony-1.4, helper

I'm trying to include an image inside a button using symfony1.4 with this code:

```
<?php 
    echo button_to(image_tag('icon.png')."button_name",'url-goes-here');
?>
```

But the result i get, instead of what i want is a button with "img src=path/to/the/icon.png button_name" as the value of the button. I've google'd it long enought and found nothing, so i'll try asking here.

### In other words:

i'd like to find the way to generate html similar to:`<button><img src=..>Text</button>` but with a symfony url associated in the onclick option

How can i do it to put an image inside a button with symfony? Am i using the helpers wrong?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: What do you want it to output? in full if possible.

Comment: symfony isn't your problem here. You need to figure out how to do the html first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally created my own helper to display this kind of buttons. I know is not very efficient and flexible but works in my case. Here is the code

```
function image_button_to($img,$name,$uri,$options){
  $sfURL = url_for($uri);
  $sfIMG = image_tag($img);
  if(isset($options['confirm'])){
    $confirm_text = $options['confirm'];
    $jsFunction = 'if(confirm(\''.$confirm_text.'\')){ return window.location=\''.$sfURL.'\';}else{return false;}';
  }else{
    $jsFunction = 'window.location="'.$sfURL.'";';
  }
  $onclick = 'onclick="'.$jsFunction.'"';
  if(isset($options['title'])){
    $title = 'title=\''.$options['title'].'\' ';
  }else{
    $title = '';
  }
  if(isset($options['style'])){
    $style = 'style=\''.$options['style'].'\' ';
  }else{
    $style = '';
  }
return '<button type="button" '.$onclick.$title.$style.' >'.$sfIMG." ".$name.'</button>';
}
```

With this function as helper, in the templates i just have to:

```
<?php echo image_button_to('image.png',"button_name",'module/actionUri');?>
```

hope this be useful for someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are using Symfonys button_to function incorrectly. From the [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_button_to):

> string button_to($name, $internal_uri, $options)  Creates an 
>   button tag of the given name pointing to a routed URL

As far as I can tell, the button_to function does not allow for image buttons. Instead, you will probably create the button tag yourself and use symfonys routing to output the url.

Comment: i don't want an image button, i want a normal button with an image inside it in addition of the $name text. The helper was used correctly, so as i understand, in my button, the image should become a part of the $name parameter of the helper. Maybe is just not possible :(

Comment: No, you cant just put an image tag or link inside the value of a submit button and have it display an image. Anything in the value will be displayed as text. If you need fancy buttons, you can create an A link, style it to look like a button, and put whatever you want in it.

Comment: i finally created a button tag by myself to add the image inside the button. Thank you for your help!