# Symfony image button for link_to function

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, link-to-function

I have a form that when originally submitted, it goes into a page where a user can "preview" the item before posting it to the site.   I have these 3 links, but I would like to change it from the default text links to image buttons that they can click on to perform these tasks.

```
  <?php echo link_to('Edit', 'ticket_edit', $ticket) ?>
  <?php echo link_to('Purchase', 'ticket_publish', $ticket, array('method' => 'put')) ?>
  <?php echo link_to("Cancel", 'ticket_delete', $ticket, array('method' => 'delete', 'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete the item?')) ?>
```

So instead of "edit", "publish", and "cancel", I want it to display an image for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<?php echo link_to( image_tag( '<your image name>' ), 'ticket_edit', $ticket) ?>
```

and so on for the other links...

Comment: Worked beautifully.   Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `button_to ($name, $internal_uri, $options)` ([Symfony docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/UrlHelper#method_button_to))

```
<?php echo button_to('Edit', 'ticket_edit', $ticket) ?>
```

but you cannot use an image as a button. However, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8854973/699091) will give you a function you can use to get what you need.